# PHP + Locking MySQL Table fails

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I have a table that needs to be locked from being inserted but it also needs to be able to be updated while inserts are prevented.

```
function myfunction() {
  $locked = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT locked FROM mylock"),0,0);
  if ( $locked ) return false;
  mysql_query("LOCK TABLES mylock WRITE");
  mysql_query("UPDATE mylock SET locked=1");
  mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES");

  /* I'm checking another table to see if a record doesn't exist already */
  /* If it doesn't exist then I'm inserting that record */

  mysql_query("LOCK TABLES mylock WRITE");
  mysql_query("UPDATE mylock SET locked=0");
  mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES");  
}
```

But this isn't enough, the function is called again from another script and simultaneously inserts are  happening from the 2 calls to the function, and I can't have that because it's causing duplicate records.

This is urgent please help. I thought of using UNIQUE on the fields but there are 2 fields (player1, player2), and NEITHER cannot contain a duplicate of a player ID.

Unwanted behavior: 
    Record A = ( Player1: 123 Player2: 456 )
    Record B = ( Player1: 456 Player2: 123 )

Comment: Also my insert statements do check if the records already exist so that is not the issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to synchronize your processes in the DB instead of doing it in the code ?

Comment: As I said this script is being ran multiple times simultaneously.  It's for a game.

Comment: your last comment does not answer my question... (I asked WHY not HOW)  another comment which is not related to your question: please avoid using `mysql_*` it's deprecated and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: How about adding some error checking? I note that mysql_result returns FALSE on error, so it's hard to see if your $locked is actually returning a row or if there's an error occurring somewhere else (no rows returned, error in the SELECT statement, etc).

Comment: I cannot error check because it's a sensitive live environment.

Comment: Checking the results of mysql_query() and mysql_result() takes *orders of magnitude* less time than making a call to MySQL. Whatever your environment is, you can afford to error check. Besides, it's obvious you have a problem somewhere. Error checking is the only way to discover what's happening in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed you suffer form a race condition in your code. Assuming there isn't an error (see my comments)... two processes could check and get "not locked" result. The "LOCK TABLES" will serialize their access, but they'll both continue on thinking they have the lock and thus duplicate records.

You could rewrite it as this:

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES mylock WRITE");
mysql_query("UPDATE mylock SET locked=1 WHERE locked=0");
$have_lock = mysql_affected_rows() > 0;
mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES");
if (!$have_lock ) return false;
```

Comment: Probably the right answer - but I am going to go with cron - Thank you for all your help. You taught me something at least. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using locks at all. Instead, when insterting the data, do like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table VALUES(<some values here>)");
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
{
    // the data was inserted without error
    $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
    // add what you need here
}
else
{
    // the data could not be inserted (because it already exists in the table)
    // query the table to retrieve the data
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE <some_condition>");
    // add what you need here
}
```

When adding the `IGNORE` keyword to an [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statement, MySQL will attempt to insert the data. If it doesn't work because a record with the same primary key is already in the table, it will fail silently. [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) is used to know the number of inserted records and decide what to do.

Comment: Thanks I thought of something like that - please check my post above I edited it (there are 2 fields and neither of them can contain a value that already exists in another row in either of the two fields)

Comment: you can add a UNIQUE key on player1, and a UNIQUE key on player2.

Comment: A unique pair (a,b) would still allow (b,a).  Do you get what I mean?

Unwanted behavior:
Record A = ( Player1: 123 Player2: 456 )
Record B = ( Player1: 456 Player2: 123 )

Comment: If those two rows are really considered equal then you should order the values so that the lower player ID always occurs as Player1. Then you can use a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need **table level** locking here, better use **row level** locking. **Row level** locking means only the one row they're modifying is locked. The usual alternatives are to either lock the entire table for the duration of the modification, or else to lock some subset of the table. Row-level locking simply reduces that subset of the rows to the smallest number that still ensures integrity.

In the InnoDB transaction model, the goal is to combine the best properties of a multi-versioning database with traditional two-phase locking. InnoDB does locking on the row level and runs queries as nonlocking consistent reads by default, in the style of Oracle. The lock table in InnoDB is stored so space-efficiently that lock escalation is not needed: Typically, several users are permitted to lock every row in InnoDB tables, or any random subset of the rows, without causing InnoDB memory exhaustion.

If your problem yet not solved, then memory size may be the issue. InnoDB stores its lock tables in the main buffer pool. This means that the number of locks you can have at the same time is limited by the innodb_buffer_pool_size variable that was set when MySQL was started. By default, MySQL leaves this at 8MB, which is pretty useless if you're doing anything with InnoDB on your server.

Luckily, the fix for this issue is very easy: adjust innodb_buffer_pool_size to a more reasonable value. However, that fix does require a restart of the MySQL daemon. There's simply no way to adjust this variable on the fly (with the current stable MySQL versions as of this post's writing).

Before you adjust the variable, make sure that your server can handle the additional memory usage. The innodb_buffer_pool_size variable is a server wide variable, not a per-thread variable, so it's shared between all of the connections to the MySQL server (like the query cache). If you set it to something like 1GB, MySQL won't use all of that up front. As MySQL finds more things to put in the buffer, the memory usage will gradually increase until it reaches 1GB. At that point, the oldest and least used data begins to get pruned when new data needs to be present.

Comment: How does locking a row help me if I am inserting new rows? :(

Comment: when a row locks, then table increases the next autoindex and cardinality. such way, when you insert new rows then the new row gets the next auto index and cardinality value. :)